# Tesseract-OCR build with visual studio 2015 on x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, 64-bit, tesseract, leptonica

I searched on the net for the built binaries of Tesseract-OCR for Visual-Studio 2015 on  x64 target, but i did not find.

I find the binaries for the Visual Studio 2013 on  x64 target here: https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/tree/master/src/lib/TesseractOcr/x64

Have anyone an idea about where I can find these binaries?

Answer (score 1):

You have to build binaries for the Visual Studio 2015 on x64 using shared solution at [visual studio 2015 and tesseract 3.05 on x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379453/visual-studio-2015-and-tesseract-3-05-on-x64?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This should be a comment.