# visual studio 2015 and tesseract 3.05 on x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, tesseract, leptonica

well i really need help here.
my problem is how can i add tesseract 3.05 and leptonica 1.73 libraries to visual studio 2015 x64 (windows 10).

i manage to do that last summer with visual studio 2013 and the older version of leptonica and tesseract because it was kinda easy and all includes and lib was there i just had to give the path and download some dll. but now i couldn't even see the right include and lib that i should use. well i'm not pro in those things so please if anyone can help me and give me some steps to do.

some guys post this link:
[https://github.com/peirick/leptonica](http://github.com/peirick/leptonica)

but no idea how to use it.

Comment: i didn't find yet the solution but i had to find (in other word i had to back) to the older solution using opencv 3.0 cause it has the x86 and use tesseract 3.0.2 and build my project as win32 using visual studio 2013 (c++).

Comment: thise link for opencv 

[link](http://blog.martinperis.com/2014/11/how-to-install-opencv-3-in-windows-8.html)

and thise for tesseract leptonica
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180824/how-to-implement-tesseract-to-run-with-project-in-visual-studio-2010)

don't forget to use the win32 API for tesseract and leptonica 

[link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/tesseract-3.02.02-win32-lib-include-dirs.zip/download?use_mirror=netix)

[link](http://www.leptonica.com/source/leptonica-1.68-win32-lib-include-dirs.zip)

Comment: sorry i'm kinda new in this website and in i libraries stuff.
i will try to find the way for the new libraries and then i will post it.

Comment: from that time to now, did you managed to change and use Tesseract 3.05 on x64? Because me too I wanted to do so and failed.

Answer (score 1):

Given link working fine, there are few steps; you can compile tesseract and leptonica in visual studio 2015

`Step1:` Take material provided from [this](https://github.com/peirick/leptonica)

`Step2:` Copy files from [this](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica) into `VS2015_Tesseract-master\leptonica\` folder

`Step3:` Copy files of tesseract from github into `VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.04` folder

`Step4:` Compile `libtesseract` or `tesseract` in `x64` platform

Done!!

Answer (score 0):

Today I built Tesseract 3.05

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Visual Studio 2015

I cloned this Repository: 
https://github.com/peirick/VS2015_Tesseract

In the resulting directory ... VS2015_Tesseract  I deleted

- subdirectory leptonica
- subdirectory tesseract_3.05

Then I opened a command prompt as administrator in VS2015_Tesseract and executed

build_tesseract.bat

1501 warnings

0 errors

To get the API work, I needed to add dependencies:

tesseract.lib;openjpeg.lib;libwebp.lib;libtiff.lib;libtesseract.lib;libpng.lib;liblept.lib;libjpeg.lib;jbig2enc.lib;giflib.lib;zlib.lib;