# Using Tesseact OCR in an existing Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, ocr, tesseract

I want to use the Tesseract-OCR library with my already existing C++ project. I followed the steps mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379453/visual-studio-2015-and-tesseract-3-05-on-x64?answertab=votes#tab-top).

1. I cloned the Github repo from [here](https://github.com/peirick/Tesseract-OCR_for_Windows)
2. Ran the `build_tesseract.bat`
3. Opened 'tesseract.sln' and set 'tesseract' as startup project before compiling it
   for both 'release' and 'debug' configurations
4. After successful compilation, under the folder 'debug' and 'release', I have a list of .lib files

Now I don't know how to move forward from here. I am used to adding libraries that have 'include' directories. Here, I am not able to find such directories except the .lib files for both 'debug' and 'release' configuration.

Can someone point me to how to use these files to add the 'tesseract-OCR' API to my existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking to use Tesseract-OCR with Visual Studio 2017+, I found an alternative method(Not exactly, It was straight to my face all along).

Using VcPkg seems to be the best and easiest way as mentioned in Tesseract-OCR documentation itself.

1. Install VcPkg from the instruction [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/README.md)
2. Navigate to the installation folder or Add the VcPkg to the 'PATH' variable
3. Run the command `vcpkg install tesseract:x64-windows`. It might take 30 to 40 mins depending on your system
4. Under the 'Installed' folder, you will find 'include', 'lib' & 'bin' folders for all Visual Studio configurations
5. Using this, you can add Tesseract-OCR to your existing Visual Studio project